# How can I develop a soccer player comparer with mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to develop a soccer player comparer website with php and mysql.
I search on google for many hours but I don't find any example.

Links:
https://pesdb.net/pes2021/?compare=4522+47179

https://www.pesmaster.com/pes-2021/compare/?id=1053098,1095755

I know how create one player stats from mysql but I don't know how create the comparer.

Comment: Provide MORE details about "I don't know how create the comparer". Where do you get stuck, what did you create so far?  and "develop a soccer player comparer" is something different than copy/pasting from the internet...

Comment: Your question is very generic, you need to let us know what exactly do you need help with and certainly we can't write the entire software for you.

Comment: I created two dropdowns with player 1 and player 2 and their stats but when i click on the player 2 stats the first disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP PDO it is just a simple query to fetch the information about the players.

Example:

```
$get_player1_id = $_GET['p1'];
$get_player2_id = $_GET['p2'];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT p.name, p.squad_number, p.position, p.offensive_awareness, p.ball_control, p.dribbling
FROM players AS p
WHERE p.p_id = :player1_id");
$query->bindValue(':player1_id', $get_player1_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$num_rows = $query->rowCount();

if ($num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $p1_name = $row['name'];
        $p1_squad_number = $row['squad_number'];
        $p1_position = $row['position'];
        $p1_offensive_awareness = $row['offensive_awareness'];
        $p1_ball_control = $row['ball_control'];
        $p1_dribbling = $row['dribbling'];

    }

}

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT p.name, p.squad_number, p.position, p.offensive_awareness,     p.ball_control, p.dribbling
FROM players AS p
WHERE p.p_id = :player2_id");
$query->bindValue(':player2_id', $get_player2_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$num_rows = $query->rowCount();

if ($num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $p2_name = $row['name'];
        $p2_squad_number = $row['squad_number'];
        $p2_position = $row['position'];
        $p2_offensive_awareness = $row['offensive_awareness'];
        $p2_ball_control = $row['ball_control'];
        $p2_dribbling = $row['dribbling'];

    }

}
```

You then just need to know html to display the information.

Example:

```
<?php

    echo '<html>

        <head>

            <title>Compare '.$p1_name.' vs. '.$p2_name.'</title>

        </head>

        <body>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Player Name:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_name.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_name.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Squad Number:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_squad_number.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_squad_number.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Position:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_position.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_position.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Offensive Awareness:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_offensive_awareness.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_offensive_awareness.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Ball Control:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_ball_control.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_ball_control.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Dribbling:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p1_dribbling.'</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>'.$p2_dribbling.'</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </body>

    </html>';

?>
```

To get the correct variables you need your URL to be like this:

[www.example.com/compare?p1=1000&p2=1001](http://www.example.com/compare?p1=1000&p2=1001)

With 1000 and 1001 being the unique id assigned to the players in your database.